Teradata Table Size
I am using the following SQL query to calculate the size of a table in Teradata:
SELECT 
     A.DatabaseName,
     A.TableName,
     B.CreateTimeStamp,
     CAST(SUM(CURRENTPERM) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/(1024*1024*1024) AS "Used(GB)"
FROM dbc.tablesizev A
JOIN dbc.tables B
  ON A.DatabaseName = B.DatabaseName
  AND A.TableName = B.TableName
WHERE A.DatabaseName = 'your_database_name'
  AND A.TableName = 'your_table_name'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 3 DESC;

I am using Teradata database version 17.20, and fallback is enabled by default in my environment.
Question:
Does the size reported by dbc.tablesizev include the size of the fallback data? Or do I need to double the reported size to get the actual disk space used by the table (including fallback copies)?

It's the actual space including Fallback and Secondary Indexes. Btw, don't use the old legacy non-V-views: it's dbc.tablesV instead of dbc.tables.
